# Uncaught type property can't be changed datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I got this error everytime i try to input a date, i can´t even open the callendar.

html

```
<td class="datapicker"><input type="hidden" name="Date" value=""/></td>
```

JS version is 1.2.6

```
$( "input[name='date']" ).datePicker();
$("td.datapicker").click( function (){
  $(this).find('input').attr('type','text').datePicker( "show" );
}).change(function (){
   val =  $(this).find('input').attr('type','hidden').val();
    $(this).find('span').remove().end().append( '<span>' + val + '</span>' );
    doAjax(val);
});

function doAjax ( valor ){
    $.ajax({
        url:  '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            data: valor   
        },
        success: function (rs){
         alert(rs);   
        }
    });
}
```

I'm stuck here for hours now..

Comment: Looks like you can't change the `type` property of the input. Have you tried simply calling `hide()` and `show()` instead?

Comment: you definitely can't change the type in IE, so i'd just skip this idea all together.

Comment: I have 2 demos http://jsfiddle.net/gravataLonga/pUbmu - this works
and this not - http://jsfiddle.net/29Rpu/
I think its from de version of javascript but i can't change it because it ruins my entire website.

Comment: You're probably refering to jQuery 1.2.6, not Javascript. And if so, the "on" handler was added 1.7

Comment: Yes jQuery sorry, my mistake. I still can't open datepicker , he keeps saying the same error.

Comment: jQuery 1.2.6 was released more than 5 years ago. Even the legacy jQuery UI is compatible only with jQuery 1.6 and up. You should update your legacy code to comply with a more recent version of jQuery, otherwise you're stuck in 2008.